# adding another column in excel being compared to another

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 spreadsheets in excel. Spreadsheet 1 contains many columns including ssn and employee ID. Spreadsheet 2 contains different columns and has an ssn column but not the employee id. I wanted create a new column in Spreadsheet 2 that is called employee id and match it with the employee's ssn that it is correlated to in Spreadsheet 1. I feel like I would need to use VLOOKUP but I am not entirely sure. Any help ? Thanks

```
=VLOOKUP(L2, [spreadhseet1.xlsx]spreadhseet1!$A:$P, 2, FALSE)
```

Above is the formula that I used. L2 is the column in table2 that contains the employee's ssn. I then took the range of all values in table1 from column A-P. Column 2 in spreadhseet2 contains the employee id which is why I entered 2. Not sure why it is providing an error

Comment: Look at the example below. You don't provide any rows. Try to change to `=VLOOKUP(L2, [spreadhseet1.xlsx]spreadhseet1!$A1:$B99999, 2, FALSE)`. No need to use up to column P since you return 2nd column index.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP is the correct function.

If you have a source similar to

```
        [A]        [B]
    1]  SSN     |  empid
       ---------------------
    2]  123     |  ABC
    3]  456     |  DEF
....
99999]  987     |  QQQ   
                   ^------- index = 2 for return value
        ^------------------ lookup is in first column
```

and want to populate destination with "empid":

```
  [a]          [b]         [c]
1] ssn |    empid    |   col2    |    col 3 | ..
  ---------------------------------------------
2] 123 |             |    B      |      C   |
3] 456 |             |    d      |      e   |

            ^----- formula here
    ^------------- this value is used as lookup
```

Then you place in the empty "empid" column a formula

`=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Sheetname'!$A2:$B9999 , 2 ,  false)`

where

A2 is your source column. 2 obviously same row.

'Sheetname'!$A2:$B99999    is your data source area, excluding header.

2 is your 1-indexed column to return

False is to return a precise match

Notice that you may be need to handle a case where lookup value does not exist in source data. This will return `#N/A` and [can be handled simply](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-n-a-error-a9708411-f82e-4e1b-8a7e-28c28311b993)

If you absolutely NEED to do this across files, it's possible, but you risk breaking something if the files are not there. [It's explained here.](https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-from-another-workbook)

*NOTICE* If you are on a non-US version of Excel, functions may separate with ";" and [have different names](https://en.excel-translator.de/searchresults/?mssearch=VLOOKUP)

Comment: Isn't row 1 the header?

Comment: I think ";" vs "," is determined by system settings, not excel language. you're correct about the different names though